# VSCode: Arduino Board Configuration offers no boards to select

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

After I used VSCode (current version 1.61.0) and the Arduino IDE (1.8.13 / 1.8.16 - WIndows installer version) for about a year  on two Windows 10 devices both devices stopped showing available Arduino / ESP8266 board types yesterday.

The Arduino board configuration only shows one item "Selected Board:" with an empty drop down.

The Arduino IDE on both devices still works (Tools - Boards show the familiar collection of boards)

My settings (searched for Arduino) are

```
{
"arduino.path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino"
}
```

on both devices - I have not changed this since the setup about a year ago and the Arduino IDE is still there und my c-drive.

What else can I check or what settings might lead to an empty board selector?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its a bug in v0.4.6 of vscode arduino extention. Roll back to v0.4.5 and before, Works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here. I think its a bug in the vscode extension. My workaround is to manually set the Bord type in the .vscode/arduino.json file. Simply add the
"board": "arduino:avr:uno", line to your json and it will work.

```
{
    "port": "COM5",
    "board": "arduino:avr:uno",
    "sketch": "example.ino"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install the board you need from:

**View / Command Palette / Arduino: Board Manager**

Then you can select your board from:

**View / Command Palette / Arduino: Board Configuration**