# "VsCode arduino extension": Cannot select board type

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, visual-studio-extensions

There is no board that I can select. [I tried to downgrade the arduino extension to v0.4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508270/vscode-arduino-board-configuration-offers-no-boards-to-select) but it didn't work, i also tried to specified manually the board in .vscode/arduino.json but it didn't work either.
[image: Arduino Board Configuration Panel]

What else can I check or what settings might lead to an empty board selector?

Comment: what is the information content of that BIG black part of the image

Comment: @MattiaGamba Can you please share how you fixed it?

Comment: @Aviad sorry, I meant that I have corrected what @ rioV8 had written in the comment

Comment: Oh, sorry. But I did find a solution in the meantime - select ctrl-shift-p, enter "arduino: board manager", and there install the package of the Arduino that you have

Comment: @Aviad Thanks, you may want to post the answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to download the boards package:
Open the command palette (`ctrl+shift+p`).
Enter `arduino: board manager` and hit enter.
Find the package that suits your board, and click install. Wait for it to finish.
Now you can come back to the "Select Board" menu and select your board.

Comment: After reading this and noticing the actual obvious situation I feel like an idiot for not thinking about that, the IDE is just so natural that changing to VS Code seems to mess with your Arduino knowledge for a bit haha.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer did not work for me.  If someone else has similar problem, you can try the following solution. Worked for me.

First kill all the vscode services using `killall`

```
sudo killall code
```

Then restart the vscode

After this, you should be able to select the board type.